# Не возвращает последний вставленный id

Tags: yii2

В Yii2 использую такую конструкцию для получения последнего вставленного id

```
Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID()
```

На моем сервере оно работает, а на сервере клиента всегда возвращает 0. В чем может быть ошибка?

Больше кода

```
 $model = new SignupForm();
 $model->email=$_POST['User']['email'];
 $model->phone=$_POST['User']['phone'];
 $model->password=Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(6);
 if ($model->signup()){
    $cons->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $cons->user_id=Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
 }
```

И вот тут

```
$cons->user_id=Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
```

Всегда 0

Comment: Покажите кусок кода побольше. Что происходит перед этим?

Comment: А `yii` разве не заполняет pk у ActiveRecord самостоятельно?

Comment: Если в код еничего не менялось, то вероятно, что различия имеют базы данных. Например, у вас MySQL, а у клиента Postgres. Укажите самое главное - информацию о БД.

Comment: нет, у клиента тоже mysql

Comment: @vp_arth, заполняет, мне надо получить его когда он его заполнил

Comment: Ну так возьмите `$model->id`, или как он там у вас называется?

Comment: так не выйдет. $model не имеет свойства id

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ваш метод load и класс SignupForm

Comment: есть еще `$model->getPrimaryKey()`

Answer (score 0):

У меня два варианта:

- Сохранение $model не происходит, но ->signup возвращает какое-то значение, поэтому Вы попадаете в тело if-а
- Сохранение $model происходит, но такая запись уже есть в БД, поэтому выполняется не insert а update

Также в настройке PDO может быть указан флаг, согласно которому каждый запрос идет отдельный соединением